Comparing the Order of STFT and Windowing in Audio Data Preprocessing for Machine Learning: Which Approach is Better?
I am designing a machine learning preprocessing pipeline for a time-series dataset and came across this paper. In the paper, the authors first apply the Short-Time Fourier Transform (STFT) to the audio data to obtain a spectrogram, and then they divide the spectrogram into chunks (windowing) to create features for training a machine learning model, specifically a Convolutional Neural Network (CNN).
I’m curious about the reasoning behind this order of operations. Could the operations be done in reverse—by first windowing the audio signal and then applying STFT to each windowed segment to obtain "spectrogram chunks" for the ML model?
Is it ok to use a rectangular window during the windowing step or are other kinds of windows needed to avoid problems? Is windowing a spectrogram different from windowing a time-series signal?
What are the potential advantages and disadvantages of each approach?

The STFT already windows the data by design: it basically moves a window (called "analysis window" along the time data and performs an FFT each time the window moves.

Could the operations be done in reverse?


Their approach is:
Compute a spectrogram on the full signal, then divide into chunks.
Your approach is:
Divide the signal into chunks, then compute a spectrogram on each chunk.

While your approach is conceptually similar, there are nuances that differentiate the two, and the most obvious one that make their approach better is the problem of edge effects:
When chunking the signal first, each chunk’s spectrogram might suffer from edge effects due to the windowing function, especially at the boundaries of each chunk. In the original method, since the entire signal is processed first, the chunks are simply divisions of an already smoothed spectrogram.

Is it ok to use a rectangular window during the windowing step or are
other kinds of windows needed to avoid problems?

It depends on your data, but in general you'd want to use tapered windows such as Hann or Kaiser windows that provide a good trade-off between time and frequency resolution while providing good side-lobe attenuation.

Is windowing a spectrogram different from windowing a time-series
signal?

Not exactly sure what you mean here, but I'm assuming you're referring to the "chunking" of the spectrogram. I haven't heard of using tapered windows to chunk an already computed spectrogram. In the paper you cite, they definitely don't use a window. Or said differently, they use a rectangular window.
"Windowing" means multiplying samples of data by samples from a "window" function. A rectangular window is one that has a value of $1$ for the duration of the window and $0$ elsewhere. It's similar to discarding part of the data and keeping the rest.

Given that the machine learning algorithm needs to run in real-time (i.e., processing the signal every second as it arrives), it’s clear that taking the spectrogram of the entire signal isn't feasible because the full signal includes future data that isn’t available yet. Does this mean that applying a windowing approach to the ongoing signal first, and then performing the STFT on each windowed segment in real-time, would make more sense in this case?
How could now mitigate the edge effects in this scenario?

@LeonardoGarofalo The FFT performed within the STFT will always process a number of time-domain samples equal to the FFT size (e.g. 4096), so the full signal does not need to be known to compute an individual spectrum.  At any given point the spectrum is entirely defined by the most recent N (FFT size) samples.  During real-time processing it would be computed continuously, with some samples having been buffered (and likely pre-windowed) for one or more pending spectrum calculations, and all others before then having been discarded as they are no longer relevant.  The same for old spectra.
